# How to reduce number of DOM elements in SPA

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a pretty complex SPA, with many tabs, views, grids, etc. Each of the elements are generated by backbone.js from a template.

Once an element is generated I want to keep a state of the element, so I cannot destroy it.

Obviously number of DOM elements with this approach is pretty high.

Is it worth the effort to de-attach a view from DOM tree once it gets hidden and re-attach it back once it gets shown?

Will backbone.js view DOM manipulation still work on de-attached element if I use `$(this.el).find()`?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would is to let the views add/remove there element from/to the DOM. So that only views that are visible have there element attached to DOM. So you can write a view manager that call the render method of the view, passing a DOM element where the view will be  rendered in. The manager can also call a stop method where he removes the views element from the DOM.